# Read in external links in PHP

Tags: php, ruby, external

I know how to do this in Ruby, but I want to do this in PHP. Grab a page and be able to parse stuff out of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). Knowing about cURL and how to use it will help in many ways as it's not specific to PHP. If you want something specific however, you can use [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) which is the recommended way in PHP to get the contents of a file into a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
$file = file_get_contents("http://google.com/");
```

How to parse it depends on what you are trying to do, but I'd recommend one of the XML libraries for PHP.

Comment: This will only work if allow_url_fopen is set to true in your php.ini file. Otherwise, you'll have to change the setting (or if you don't have access to it, then cURL is your only other option).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) in read mode: `fopen($url, 'r');` or more simply `file_get_contents($url);`. You could also use `readfile()`, but `file_get_contents()` is potentially more efficient and therefore recommended.

Note: these are dependent on config (see the linked manual page) but will work on most setups.

For parsing, simplexml is enabled by default in PHP.

```
$xmlObject = simplexml_load_string($string);
// If the string was valid, you now have a fully functional xml object.

echo $xmlObject->username;
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplexml bit, that will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Its funny, I had the opposite question when I started rails development

Comment: Yeah, I worked that out when I was doing automated google searches (googleplainly.com). Year later and I still haven't linked everything up to automatically add results to the database. But the ruby fetching work fine.